# Website to identify low season for hotels

Tags: budget, online-resources, planning, hotels, seasonal

I use online booking websites (Agoda, Booking.com, ...) to check hotels prices; But they are good when you know the time of travel.

I want to plan my vacation and it can be any time. So, I started to search for "when is the low rates season for hotels?".

Is there a website which provides this?

**EDIT**: When I search on booking.com for a certain hotel, I get different prices on different days in the year.

**EDIT**: I am looking for worldwide website (even if it is collection of booking.com's prices). But I am interested in middle east hotels.

Comment: This might be easier to answer for a specific place rather than in general because different places have different low seasons.

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee As I understand he wants a website that checks *worldwide* for lowest price where season doesn't matter.

Comment: Lonely planet sometimes mentions when the low and high seasons are if the difference is major.

Comment: EU publishes the pattern for Europe: http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/statistics_explained/index.php/Seasonality_in_the_tourist_accommodation_sector

Comment: One answer recommended LateRooms.com, it can display prices for 2 weeks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Europe at least, this site on [Seasonality in Tourism Demand for Europe](http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/statistics_explained/index.php/Seasonality_in_tourism_demand) is going to be a great start - it has graphs galore, detailing which countries get how many tourists, and why, and when.  It's a really good read.

Now, to do your own research is probably the best way to find out low season for any particular destination.  You'll want to investigate a few factors..

**Climate** - researching what the expected climate is in the destination you choose is *very* important. Rainy seasons, seasons of irregular weather, extreme heat or cold can all ruin a holiday.  This really is one of the most serious considerations when choosing an off peak holiday.

**Attractions** - many places you may wish to visit, the attractions are seasonal.  Hawaii is warmer in summer.  Northern lights are barely visible in summer - best in winter.  Snowboarding is best in winter - you need snow, for example.

**Air fares** - many airlines tweak their fares for seasonal demand. You can use [kayak.com](http://www.kayak.com) to check fares ahead of time, and set alerts for when deals appear.

**Hotels** - similar to airfares, you can set alerts on some booking sites ([booking.com](http://www.booking.com), and check ahead to see when deals or discounts appear.  Planning is essential, sometimes airfares and hotel deals aren't available for long, so if you know your dates and budget, you can take advantage of the deals when you see them.

Good luck!

Comment: +1 for booking.com/kayak.com deals alerts. It seems there are no website which provides such info. Accepted as the only semi-automated solution.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think one website exists that contains details on the low season of every location on the planet.

But to be honest, I don't think you really need one. It is fairly easy to figure out when the low season is of any particular area. If it doesn't pop right away in a google search, just look at the weather of the place you want to go. Whenever it rains the most is the coldest, 99% of the time that is the low season.

Comment: and you have a resource to show it? I tried weather.com and I didn't find information for more than 2 months around now. And I don't think Wikipedia has this information for everywhere.

Comment: @Vince wunderground.com has historical data for almost anywhere I've looked (or at least a major place nearby) which would give a good indication.